# Missing parts in a Lego Mindstorms box

Tags: piece-information, mindstorms, replacement-parts

Could it be that there are parts missing in a LEGO box? I've a new set of [LEGO Mindstorms *(reference number 31313)*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=120857) and I'm missing the parts

**4499858**

[image]

**4211805**

[image]

Where could I get them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get replacement Mindstorms NXT components?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/how-can-i-get-replacement-mindstorms-nxt-components)

Comment: Every time I have thought a part was missing from a LEGO box, it's been in a bag that I missed, or in a bag that I thought I'd emptied and put aside (but it still had a part in it), or it's rolled away somewhere. Have you double-, triple-, and quadruple-checked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a brand new set, and a few parts are missing, you should definitely contact LEGO Customer Service, so they can send you the parts you are missing.

> **New sets with missing parts**
>
> We’re really sorry to hear that something was missing from your new LEGO® set. We do our best to make every set perfect and we take it very seriously when a faulty one sneaks through. Don’t worry though, we can send you the parts you need!
>
> Please click “Missing Bricks” on the Bricks & Pieces section of our [Customer Service site](https://www.lego.com/service/replacementparts) to order the part you need to finish your set.
>
> If you can’t find what you’re looking for, make sure you include a complete description of the part (the part number provided in the inventory page at the back of the building instructions is useful) along with the set number. Once your part is on its way, we’ll send you a shipping confirmation email.
>
> If you’ve lost some bricks over time, please remember to click “Buy Bricks” instead.
>
> -- [LEGO Customer Service FAQ](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/help/bricks-building/replacement-parts/new-sets-with-missing-parts-408100000007736)

Just tell them the part numbers you are missing and they should send you the parts for free.

Comment: FWIW, my son received a LEGO kit earlier this month that was missing an entire bag of parts and the instruction book (the factory tape was intact). I contacted customer service via email and two weeks later, have yet to receive a response.

Comment: @alroc That's unusual, you should definitely contact them again.

Comment: @alroc - Perhaps their policy limits how much they'll send you for free, but they should not just ignore you. I'd try calling them again. As an alternative, you could exchange it at the store you purchased it at. If you've already started building out the set and don't want to return it, bring everything to the store and explain it, and they might accommodate you by allowing you to remove the parts from a new box and they'll return it to Lego. Otherwise, buy it again and get your replacement parts. Put remaining new parts in old box and return it on original purchase receipt.

Comment: To add to @KevinFegan's return recommendation, if it was purchased at a LEGO Brand Retail Store, at-least in the US, they might not take a return of an open box. I believe it's their policy now to instead direct you to customer service for replacements (I assume because scammers abused this).

Comment: We're wildly off-topic at this point but seemingly on cue, I got a response from LEGO about 4 hours after I wrote my comment. But at this point it's too late, we got a gift receipt for it and exchanged at the store a couple days ago because we didn't want to keep waiting.

Answer (score 4):

You can purchase them both at *[Bricklink.com.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page)*

***[Here](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=55013&name=Technic,%20Axle%208%20with%20Stop&category=%5BTechnic,%20Axle%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*** for *ElementID #4499858*, and
[image]

***[Here](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44294&ccName=4211805#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:86,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*** for *ElementID #4211805*.[image]

> Could it be that there're parts missing in a LEGO box?

Yes, it is possible that pieces do end up missing from the time a set leaves the *LEGO* factory to the time the box ends up in our hands.

Without further information we don't know the exact reasons why this happens without proper polling, collecting, and disseminating these results.

We could speculate the reasons through past experiences.  In the past I had recently finished watching the movie *Gremlins* and was sure one of those things got into my box and took a piece, but in reality that piece was stuck in the inner crevasse of the box.

So, for me: User error or *self-Trolling* was the culprit.

[image]

Or at any rate, you can follow what *Alexander O'Mara* has suggested, and contact *LEGO Customer Service* to get your parts replaced for free.

Comment: Sorry but your answer  it doesn't answer my first question, **could it be that there're parts missing**?

Answer (score 2):

> Could it be that there're parts missing in a LEGO box?

Rin Rio-Oki has pointed you to the place where you can definitely get replacement parts, but to answer your first question, yes, it is indeed possible, though the chances for it are negligible. In any case, you should let LEGO know about it via their official support channels (even if you are planning to get the replacement parts from Bricklink), so that they are aware of the problem and can take steps to mitigate such accidents in the future.